# Cooperation tool group: coding in C

Tags: c, codepad

Is there any tool, similar to codepad, writing code in C language that I can share my code with a group and my group can make changes and simultaneous views in real time editing?

Comment: Hmmm. Use a Google Doc with Consolas font? :D

Comment: uhm.... you'll have no idea who broke the code as people were editing simultaneously the same code. it's a bit hard to find a good use case for the tool you're asking for.

Comment: I've tried ... But Google Docs has some problems such as weak indentation (or zero), has no highlight, finally, is a collaborative tool to program but is not there.

Comment: I know the risks but I want a tool like this. It is a collaborative group, group people do not change randomly.

Comment: yeah but some things like code refractoring spanning a couple of files will give you serious headaches.. I just tried to warn you, that's all ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you enough that this is going to make your work more difficult if you're planning on using this for anything other than something like a code review. However, it's called a real-time collaborative editor. There are a ton of them. I used one on linux a while back that I can't remember the name of, but in the mean-time, let wikipedia start you off...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor

Edit:

The tool I used on Linux that worked well was called [*Gobby*](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/).

There are a bunch of others in this question on SO [Real time tool for collaborative coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028358/real-time-tool-for-collaborative-coding)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting an old question but I thought I should share this.
I usually use **Collab.Center** **(http://collab.center)**. Some features I like about it better than others are:

- Online, real-time collaborative coding
- Support for a lot of languages (40+, I think) (EX: C, C++, Java, HTML/CSS/JS, PHP, etc)
- Text and Video (Webcam) chat (Requires Sign-In)
- Syntax highlighting, auto-closing brackets, matching brackets, etc.
- Ability to manage all your documents (Requires Sign-In)
- Private documents (Requires Sign-In)

I think it would be great for you and your group, if you haven't already found an alternative.

Comment: 2 years later, this almost feels like spam.  Not quite, but close.  In the future, be careful about resurrecting old posts just to add info that feels like advertising.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Should I delete it?

Comment: I'll leave that to others to decide.  I could have deleted it, but left it alone as it does add useful info.  But I double checked your profile to see if you were spamming elsewhere due to the nature of this post.  Again, I think it's ok, but not 'great'  :)

Comment: I am very glad that you added new content here. It will be very helpful for me and for anyone searching for this kind of tool (: